# Синхронизация с exchange

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, есть ли какое АПИ или как можно работать с exchange

Answer (score 2):

Есть

- [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)
- [EWS Java API 1.1](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi)

Насколько это все работоспособно на Android, сказать трудно. Пример приложения -  [Corporate Address Book](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/), - работающего с [Exchange Server Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307725(v=EXCHG.80).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо. Статьи вчера тоже эти нашел. Думал, может, кто пользовался чем-то из, чтобы немного проконсультировал.